# Need help learning Liferay 7 MVC

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Are there any basic tutorials for creating my first liferay 7 portlet like a Hello World App?

I am new to Liferay and need some help getting started. I have read over the liferay 7 tutorials and I have tried following the Liferay 7 Creating An MVC Portlet, but having trouble understanding where everything goes and how it all works together, and I feel that it is not a comprehensive tutorial.

**About Me and My Liferay Aspirations:**

- I have experience with JAVA, JavaScript and Node.js.
- I'd eventually like to be able to display a google map and display content on it, but just want to make some baby steps understanding portlets. Correct me if a portlet is not the right thing for me to be focusing on for this goal.

Comment: You can display a google map with anything, portlet or not. However, Stackoverflow has explicitly opted to *not* be a platform to recommend exterhal resources, tutorials and documentations. And another hint: You don't even mention *which* Liferay tutorials don't help you (not that this would make the question more in focus).and where exactly your problems were (*this* might transform the question to be in focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent book "Liferay in Action". It helpls a lot, but there are a lot of mistakes in code. On the other hand, there is "Portlet in action", but it doesn't have free pdf-version :\

Also, you can visit web.liferay.com, I don't like this forum but there are good questions from time to time.

And any other issues you can only google, google and google again. Unfortunately, there is no alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorials are not going to give you all the details, because they must be as short as possible. That said, the [Creating an MVC Portlet](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-an-mvc-portlet) tutorial should get you pretty well on your way. Which parts, specifically, are you having trouble understanding?

Have you read the [Liferay MVC Portlet](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/liferay-mvc-portlet) introductory tutorial? It's even sparser on details but it might fill in a few gaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are first time developing using liferay then [this link might help you.](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/) It is guide to liferay 6.2. Creating plugin portlets is same in liferay 6.2 and 7. Just setup is different.

For creating liferay modules refer liferay 7 documentation.